# MediaQuery.of(context) causing error in Flutter app

Tags: android, flutter, dart, orientation

I have had this problem of android emulator Keyboard disappearing after clicking on TextFormField that I exposed in [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71451985/android-emulator-keyboard-automatically-disappears-when-selecting-flutter-textfo)

Here is the error :

```
Unhandled Exception: 'package:flutter/src/animation/animation_controller.dart': Failed assertion: line 454 pos 7: '_ticker != null': AnimationController.forward() called after AnimationController.dispose()
package:flutter/…/animation/animation_controller.dart:454
E/flutter (10562): AnimationController methods should not be used after calling dispose.
```

When I remove the AnimationController, there is no more error but there is still the unexpected behavior of the keyboard disappearing when I click on the TextFormField.

There is a widget that I created : TaskCard, that I use in many screens of my app.

Here are 2 of them :

[image]

In all the parent widgets (the screens using it) of this TaskCard I call MediaQuery.of(context) in the build to get the following data and make the design of my app responsive to screen sizes and shapes :

```
orientation = MediaQuery.of(context).orientation;
    screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    screenHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
```

I made a new topic because I found out that this part was actually causing the error, when I remove it everything works fine.

Also, the error only pops up when I am running on an emulator, it works fine on web.

If anyone have a workaround for this it would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here was code of the children of the ListView that I call in my parent widget to generate my TaskCard :

```
List<Column> tasksToListTile(){
return tasks.map((e) => Column(
  key: UniqueKey(),
  children: [
    TaskCard(p3provider: widget.p3provider, task: e, fromCalendar: false, fromTaskDetail: false, actualizeParent: refresh, statusChange: false),
    Container(
      height: 5.0,
      color: BeoColors.darkGreyBlue
    )
  ]
)).toList();
```

}

This code is called in the build of the parent widget, so everytime it would rebuild the function UniqueKey() would generate a new key and that's what create the problem.

To fix that I create the number of keys that I need outside the build (in the initState in my case) and add it to a list (here I use the List keys for the keys, and I use the List tasks to count the number of TaskCards I will need to generate) :

```
for (int i = 0; i < tasks.length; i++) {
      keys.add(GlobalKey());
      print(keys[i].toString());
    }
```

and then use it in the ReorderableListView :

```
for (int i =0; i < tasks.length; i++)
          Column(
            key: keys[i],
            children: [
              TaskCard(p3provider: widget.p3provider, task: tasks[i], fromCalendar: false, fromTaskDetail: false, actualizeParent: refresh, statusChange: false),
              Container(
                height: 5.0,
                color: BeoColors.darkGreyBlue
              )
            ],
          )
```